# How could std::atomic::load be implemented

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency

Let's say I wanted to implement an own std::atomic type (of course I don't want, I am only asking out of curiosity). How would I implement the load method? My guess would be something like the following (`m_mutex` is the mutex used to lock the operations and `m_object` the object that atomic is currently holding):

```
T& load() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m_mutex);

    return m_object;
}
```

Obviously, this would not work because when calling `a.load().doSomething()` the call to `doSomething` would not be protected because `m_object` it is already returned from `load` and not guarded by the lock_guard any more.

I would like to ask two questions:

1. How would one implement a correct version of load?
2. What would be a simple technique to realize `load` not with a mutex but with a lock-free datastructure?

Comment: It would use target and processor specific instructions & features.

Comment: You mean inline assembly code in the implementation of std::atomic? Just very simplified, how would that look like?

Comment: Either inline assembly, or builtin features inside the compiler.

Comment: What would be built-in features inside the compiler? I mean there must be some C++ implementation of the atomic.h / atomic.cpp?

Comment: Look into [target builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Target-Builtins.html) and [atomic builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) chapters of GCC documentation; also the compiler knows about the atomic qualifier.

Comment: This is why `std::atomic::load` returns by value.

Comment: Ok, now I am confused. I was pretty sure it returns be reference. How can I access then the member that atomic protects by reference if I want to do changes on it (and not put the pointer to the object inside atomic)?

Comment: You don't. You make a copy with load, compute the new value, and then store new value back in, probably in a loop with compare_exchange.

Answer (score 1):

> How would one implement a correct version of load?

```
template <typename T>
class atomic {
public:
  static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>(),
                "atomic<T> requires trivially copyable T");

  // ...

  // Ignores the memory ordering parameter and always provides
  // sequential consistency. This is *correct*, but possibly
  // sacrifices performance.
  T load(std::memory_order) const noexcept {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{mtx_};
    return t_;
  }

private:
  std::mutex mtx_;
  T t_;
};
```

> What would be a simple technique to realize load not with a mutex but with a lock-free datastructure?

Lock-free data structures in c++ are implemented with lock-free atomic objects. The implementation of *lock-free* atomic objects is not possible within the confines of standard C++; they need support from compiler intrinsics and/or platform-specific inline assembly to perform atomic memory operations with proper ordering guarantees. Take at look at the implementation of `std::atomic` in the standard library of your choice for many gory details.

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously, this would not work because when calling
>   a.load().doSomething() the call to doSomething would not be protected
>   because m_object it is already returned from load and not guarded by
>   the lock_guard any more.

This is an inevitable side effect of this interface and cannot be changed by any implementation. If you want to not just *load* it but also protect some other random functionality on it, then that's a whole different kettle of fish.

If you thought that this was safe with `std::atomic`, it's not.